# php mysqli error on some browsers only

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am getting this error on only some browsers and I am not sure why. I am hoping this is a simple fix. It sounds like it should be. Here is the error and below that is the code.

**warning : mysqli_fetch_array expects parameters 1 to mysqli_result, boolean given in /home/content/yada/html/myapp/main.php on line 71**

By the way, this is line 71:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
```

and below is the full code

```
$type = $_POST[type];
$user="theUser";
$password="thePassword";
$database="theDatabase";
$TABLE = "user";

@mysql_connect("mydb.com",$user,$password);
@mysql_select_db($database) or die("Unable to select database");

if($_POST[type]) {
    $query = "UPDATE $TABLE 
              SET type = $type
              WHERE fbId = $id";

    if(mysql_query($query)) {
        //echo "Settings saved successfully!";
    } else {
        echo ("MySQL Error: ".mysql_error());
    }
}

$con=mysqli_connect('localhost',"$user","$password","$database");

// Check connection
if(mysqli_connect_errno($con)) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM $TABLE WHERE fbID = $id");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $currentType = $row['type'];
    //echo $currentType;
}   

if ($result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM $TABLE WHERE fbID = $id", MYSQLI_USE_RESULT)) {
    //echo "True";
    //mysqli_free_result($result);
}
```

Comment: That can't be line 71. Line 71 has to have `mysqli_fetch_array()`.

Comment: Shouldn't `$_POST[type]` be `$_POST['type']`?

Comment: let me double check.. thanks

Comment: Why are you using both `mysql` and `mysqli` in the same program?

Comment: Where is $id declaration?

Comment: why are you connecting twice to the same db, once with mysqli and once with mysql?!

Comment: This code is insecure. Please read about SQL Injections and fix the code.

Comment: I didn't even notice. I added some code someone else did. This double connect could be causing the issue.

Comment: You need to check the result of `mysqli_query()`, just like you do with `mysql_query()`.

Comment: @Tero do you recomend a website to help me understand how to make it more secure?

Comment: @PapaDeBeau See the second **Related** question.

Comment: $id is declared above, I did not add that code because it would be too long. I tried to focus on the issue code.

Comment: @Barmar, but why does $_POST[type] not get en error? Why do I need the ''?

Comment: If you turn on warnings, you'll get a warning about that. PHP automatically converts `type` to `'type'`.

Comment: Why do you do the same `SELECT` query twice -- once before the `while` loop, and again after it? And why do you need a `while` loop? There's only one row being returned, right?

Comment: The error you got means there was a problem executing your SQL. You need to print `mysqli_error()` to find out what it was. While it's unusual to use both mysql and mysqli in the same program, it shouldn't cause an error.

Comment: Yes @Barmar there is only one row

Comment: So why do you have a loop when there's nothing to iterate over? Just because you use a `while` loop when processing queries that return multiple rows, it doesn't mean you always have to use a loop. Think about what you're writing when you program, don't just copy code blindly.

Answer (score -1):

Use
    echo mysqli_error($con);
to show the error MySQL server gives when executing the SQL query on line 71. This will reveal what is wrong with the query.